# django: python manage.py и python manage.py runserver не работают

Tags: python, django

Выдаётся такая ошибка:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: Не найден указанный модуль.

(venv) C:\Users\shturmanser\Desktop\untitled6\django_foxford>pip install sqlite3
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sqlite3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sqlite3

(venv) C:\Users\shturmanser\Desktop\untitled6\django_foxford>pip install _sqlite3
ERROR: Invalid requirement: '_sqlite3'
```

Подскажите, как это исправить?

Comment: `sqlite3` уже есть "из коробки" в питоне, его ставить не нужно

Comment: Я когда запускаю код, он пишет, что "_sqlite3: Не найден указанный модуль." и пытается установить. Я так понимаю, на этом программа и рушится. Что можно с этим сделать?

Comment: попробуйте создать другой проект. Если ошибка повторится, то напишите какие команды запускали. Эта ошибка крайне специфичная, в 99.99% случае ее просто нет

Comment: попробуйте `python3 manage.py` , может из-за версии питона ругается

Comment: @Ann_S123, а покажите вывод команды python -m pip freeze

Comment: или переустановите сам питон

Comment: @Za Ars, "python3 не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом." Не помогло к сожалению. Сейчас попробую создать другой проект

Comment: А если выполнить импорт с вашей версией питона `import sqlite3`, тоже будет эта ошибка? Погуглил про эту ошибку и она возникает обычно у линуксоидов с версией питона, без включенной поддержкой sqlite3, т.е. в той версии в бинарнике питона отсутствует библиотека для sqlite3. Думаю, у вас что-то подобное приключилось с библиотекой для sqlite3, поэтому переустановка питона может помочь

Comment: Андрей Коробейников, antiorm==1.2.1
asgiref==3.3.4
db==0.1.1
db-sqlite3==0.0.1
Django==3.2.4
pytz==2021.1
sqlparse==0.4.1

Comment: @gil9red, да, при импорте ошибка тоже появляется. Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @Ann_S123, интересно чем закончилось? Пробовали просто без python написать `manage.py runserver`?

Comment: Андрей Коробейников, да, пробовала. При manage.py runserver просто открывается файл manage.py. Сейчас всё ещё гуглю решение проблемы

Comment: Покажите вывод команды `python -VV`

Comment: @Spatz, Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 17:30:36) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: Похоже, что у вас нестандартный дистрибутив. Установите с [оф. сайта](https://www.python.org/)

Comment: Spatz, хорошо, попробую. Спасибо

Comment: Нашла рабочее решение здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876404/unable-to-import-sqlite3-using-anaconda-python